# Delete Operation is not working using PHP POP Delete modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using PHP modal to take confirmation for deleting the record from table, but it is not working. The pop modal is appearing even it become submit but unfortunately the record is not being deleted. any idea why this operation can't be done. please provide me the exact solution, what I can do to become fix.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['deletedata']))
  {  
    $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id=$id");
    header("Location:gallery.php"); 
  }
?>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deletebtn").on('click', function() {
      $(".deletemodal").modal('show');
      var deletedId = $(this).closest("tr").find(':first-child').text();
      $("#delete_id").val(deletedId);
    });
  });
</script>
 <!---POP Delete Modal --->
 <div class="modal fade" id="deletemodal" class="deletemodal"role="dialog" 
 aria-hidden="true" ><div class="modal-dialog" >
 <div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Delete Image</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="gallery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
        data">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="delete_id"  id="delete_id">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this image?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" style="margin-right:-5px;" 
              name="deletedata" class="btn btn-primary" >Yes</button>
                <button type="button"  style="margin-top:-2px;" class="btn 
         btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </form></div></div> </div>
<!---Gallery Table Start --->
<div class="candile">
  <div class="candile-inner" style="margin-top:-40px;">
    <h3 style="color:#002561">Gallery</h3>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gmodal" 
    class="btn btn-lg btn-default">ADD</button>
    <div class="graph">
      <div class="tables">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="th-sm">ID</th>
              <th class="th-sm">Title</th>
              <th class="th-sm">Content</th>
              <th class="th-sm">Image</th>
              <th class="th-sm">Edit</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr></thead><tbody>
            <?php
while($datarecord=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultrecord))?>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                  <?php echo $datarecord["id"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                  <?php echo $datarecord["title"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $datarecord["content"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                  <?php echo '<img src="images/'.$datarecord['gimage'].'">';?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editegmodal" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning warning_11 
  editebtn" id="editegbtn" value="Edit"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" value="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletemodal" class="btn btn-lg btn- 
  danger deletebtn" id="deletebtn"></td>
              </tr>
              <?php}?></tbody></table></div></div> </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change edit button with attr id
<input type="button" value="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#deletemodal" class="btn btn-lg btn- 
danger deletebtn" id="deletebtn" id="<?php echo $datarecord["id"]; ?>">

change button event
var deletedId = $(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont have any element with 'delete_id' name and id in your form, so when you submit the form, there are no $_POST['delete_id']

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded wrong modal, but now fixed, check it please.

Comment: var_dump ($_POST), and add mysqli_error($con) to check error.